# How to truncate field in git log --pretty

Tags: git

We have some people with long names in our git commit logs.  Currently, my format is

```
pretty = %C(yellow)%h%Creset %s %C(red)(%an, %cr)%Creset
```

which shows

```
276840c Kyle Heironimus Added updated hello world example. (3 months ago)
```

I really just want

```
276840c Kyle Added updated hello world example. (3 months ago)
```

If I can't just take the first word of the author name, the first 5 characters would be my second choice.

Any way to do this?

Comment: There isn't a real answer to the question. I would like have a pretty format which truncates all names to 5 characters, or the first name, without having a mailmap file with all of them in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use %aN rather than %an, Git will consider aliases listed in ~/.mailmap when displaying author names.  If you create that file, and add, say -

`Kyle <youremail@example.com>`

then you should get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks! That did it.  I had to adjust my .gitconfig to add `[mailmap]
 file = /Users/kyle/.mailmap` to use a global mailmap.

Comment: On git version 2.5.0  (on OSX 10.10.x), using tilde also worked for me : `git config --global --add mailmap.file "~/.mailmap"`